Как заставить программу читать токен из файла
Я хочу сделать IRC клиент на python через Telegram, и я хочу, чтоб у меня не валялся токен в самом файле, а чтобы программа читала его с определённого файла, который будет в той же директории, что и .py файл. Как это сделать? Код ниже
import logging
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, CallbackContext
import irc.client

# Настройка логирования
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

# Ваш токен Telegram бота
TELEGRAM_TOKEN = [обращение к *.txt файоу в той же директории, где написан токен]

# Класс для работы с IRC
class MyIRCClient(IRCClient):
    def __init__(self, nickname, password):
        super().__init__()
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.password = password

    def connect(self, server, port):
        # Здесь добавьте логику подключения к IRC
        pass

# Функция для старта бота
def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    update.message.reply_text('Привет! Пожалуйста, введите ваш никнейм.')

# Функция для обработки никнейма
def handle_nickname(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    context.user_data['nickname'] = update.message.text
    update.message.reply_text('Спасибо! Теперь введите ваш пароль.')

# Функция для обработки пароля
def handle_password(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    context.user_data['password'] = update.message.text
    nickname = context.user_data['nickname']
    password = update.message.text

    # Подключение к IRC
    irc_client = MyIRCClient(nickname, password)
    irc_client.connect('irc.ppy.sh', 6667)  # Замените на ваш IRC сервер и порт
    update.message.reply_text('Подключение к IRC серверу...')

def main() -> None:
    updater = Updater(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)

    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, handle_nickname))
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, handle_password))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Кажется, про чтение файлов должно быть написано в любом учебнике по питону

Стандартное решение - использование .env файла:
.
├── .env

# Development settings
TELEGRAM_TOKEN = '0000000000:AAAA1aA1aa1a1AA1Aa_Aaa1AaAAaaAaaaa'


└── main.py

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

TELEGRAM_TOKEN = os.getenv('TELEGRAM_TOKEN')

print(TELEGRAM_TOKEN)


pip install python-dotenv

pyyaml
.
├── .secret.yaml
---
API_ID: 12345678
API_HASH: 33ee333eeeeee3333e333ee3e333e333
S_SESSION: !!null
WONDER_BOT: 0000000000:AAAA1aA1aa1a1AA1Aa_Aaa1AaAAaaAaaaa
W_SESSION: !!null
BIGWELD_BOT: 1111111111:BBBB1bB1bb1b1BB1Bb_Bbb1BbBBbbBbbbb
B_SESSION: !!null
DEBUG: true
...

├── .clients.yaml
---
clients:
  client: !!python/object:pyrogram.client.Client
    name: "client"
    api_id: !!secret "API_ID"
    api_hash: !!secret "API_HASH"
    session: !!secret "S_SESSION"
    in_memory: !!bool true
  bigweld: !!python/object:pyrogram.client.Client
    name: "bigweld"
    api_id: !!secret "API_ID"
    api_hash: !!secret "API_HASH"
    bot_token: !!secret "BIGWELD_BOT"
    session: !!secret "B_SESSION"
    in_memory: !!bool true
  wonder: !!python/object:pyrogram.client.Client
    name: "wonder"
    api_id: !!secret "API_ID"
    api_hash: !!secret "API_HASH"
    bot_token: !!secret "WONDER_BOT"
    session: !!secret "W_SESSION"
    in_memory: !!bool true

DEBUG: True
...

├── __init__.py
# Можно инициализировать бота здесь.
import yaml


def secret_constructor(loader, node) -> str | int:
    """Субконструктор для pyrogram.client.Client."""

    # тут пара строк...

def client_constructor(loader, node) -> 'Client':
    """Конструктор для pyrogram.client.Client."""

    # здесь чуть побольше строк...

yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(
    'tag:yaml.org,2002:secret', secret_constructor)
yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(
    'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object:pyrogram.client.Client', client_constructor)

clients = yaml.safe_load(open(r".clients.yaml"))
client, bigweld, wonder =  None, None, None
globals().update({name: client_ for name, client_ in clients["clients"].items()})

└── main.py
# Либо здесь.
import yaml


def dump_session_string(key: str, session_string: str) -> NoReturn:
    """Сохранение сессионной строки в .secret.yaml."""
    
    pass

